# Close the all Activity of Current Application and launch Play store

Tags: android

Is it possible to start an **implicit activity** on the stack, by clearing the entire history before it?

I am creating an application which have a concept of force upgrade from playsotre.
therefore I want to open play store at some moment and same moment I also want to close my application basically I want clear all activity of my Application after opening play store, but it didn't work.

My code snip:

```
btnForceUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                        .setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName()));
                goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // clearing all activity task (Basically close the app)
                mDialog.cancel();
                context.startActivity(goToMarket);
            }
        });
```

I am using below flag in intent object but it didnt work

```
goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // clearing all activity task (Basically close the app)
```

Comment: can you tell me what happen currently i think it will start google play store but not clear current activity

Comment: @PankajAndroid , Yes are right it open play store but did not clearing my application activity stack

Comment: try {
            final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName()));
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            finishAffinity();
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (final android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: how about new task flag and finishaffinity_

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu Same behavior with `finishAffinity()`

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal can  you tell me your first activity(last activity which is in current statck) so i can help you

Comment: @PankajAndroid thanks for your quick responce, First Activity is LoginActivity and last Activity is Dynamic so we can not relay on last Activity statically.

Comment: Calling finish affinity before startActivity works for me. just wondering .

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal see my answer: make one new activity and start that activity and before start closeactivity you need to finish that activity and clear stack. now close activity is only in stack and when you start google play you need to finish close acitivity this will close whole app

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu `finishAffinity` is working on api level 15+ thank you.

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal working or not ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  try {

        final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName()));
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        finishAffinity();
        startActivity(i); // 

   } catch (final android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or if you want it to work in previous versions(< 15 API) of Android:

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make one activity with start google play like below

```
public class CloseActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); 
    try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        finish();
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Need to start this activity from class with below code:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,CloseActivity.class);
mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(mIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: This could be a solution but i do not aware which will be become the CurrentActivity in future.

Comment: CurrentActivity is the activity from right now you are starting Google play application. you need to make one single activity which i have mention with xml now you need to start that activity and it will start google play and close you application

Comment: Tell me your activity name from where you are starting this intent goToMarket= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                        .setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName()));